# Convert a string into a GmailThread object

Tags: gmail-addons

How can you convert a string into a GmailThread object?

```
var threadid = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('threadid');  
var msgs = threadid.getMessages(); //error
```

Thks,
jfg

Answer (score 0):

[Check](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getThreadById(String)) `getThreadById(id)` of `GmailApp`. Hence your code will be like:

```
var thread = GmailApp.getThreadById(threadId);
var msgs = thread.getMessages();
```